# If $f_{n-1}(x)=nf_{n}'(x)$ , write $ f_n(x)$ as a function of $f_1(x)$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $f_{n-1}(x)=nf_{n}'(x)$ for all $n>1$, and $f_1(x)=a$, what is the expression depicting the relationship between $ f_n(x)$ and $f_1(x)$? I need help with this series.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly see that $f'_n(x)=nf''_{n-1}(x)$ and iteratively $f^{(k)}_n(x)=nf^{(k+1)}_{n-1}(x)$. And so $f_n(x)=nf'_{n-1}(x)=n^nf^{(n)}_1(x)$.

Comment: @numthcurios in the stem?

Comment: please see my edited question. Disregard the stem statement.